# Regularized underdetermined system of linear equations, different norms for regularization

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations

For the following underdetermined equation system:

$a^Tx=b$ $\qquad$ with:
$x = (x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3$,  $a=(1, 1/2, 1/4)$ and $b=1$

I want to compute the solution of the following $l_0, l_1$ and $l_2$ regularized problems:

$\min ||x||_0 $ subject to $a^Tx=b$

$\min ||x||_1 $ subject to $a^Tx=b$

$\min ||x||_2 $ subject to $a^Tx=b$

For $l_0$ and $l_1$ regularization the solution seems to be quite obvious:

$x = (1, 0, 0)$

However I'm not quite sure how to calculate the solution for the $l_2$ regularization.

Comment: What does finding the Euclidean distance from the origin $(0,0,0)$ to the hyperplane $a^{\text{T}} x = b$ give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of $l_0$ is all $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ with either $x_1=0$ or $x_2=0$ or $x_3=0$. For $l_1$ the answer is the only one you obtained and for $l_2$ we need to minimize $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2$ s.t. $x_1+x_2/2+x_3/4=1$. Using Lagrange multipliers we have$$L(x,\lambda)=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2-\lambda(x_1+\dfrac{x_2}{2}+\dfrac{x_3}{4})$$by taking partial differentiation we arrive at:$$2x_1=\lambda\\2x_2=\frac{\lambda}{2}\\2x_3=\frac{\lambda}{4}$$and by substituting in the constraint we have$$\lambda=\frac{32}{21}$$therefore the minimum would be attained when $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(\dfrac{16}{21},\dfrac{8}{21},\dfrac{4}{21})$ and its value is $$m=(\dfrac{16}{21})^2+(\dfrac{8}{21})^2+(\dfrac{4}{21})^2=\dfrac{256}{21}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Can you just explain to me why there is a minus in front of lambda and not a plus?

Comment: This is a convention in convex optimization. The plus or minus sign don't differ when your constraints are all in kind of equality but when having one or more equality among those, the negative sign yields to positive $\lambda$. For here, there is no difference. Feel free to change signs....